# Embed: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

It's me again..

Alright so:

I'm trying to make a command that will warn users they joined a wrong server, But when I run the command, I get the Cannot send an empty msg error..

Really, any help would be appreciated!

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args, err) => { 
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle('Hey!').setDescription('We think you have our server mistaken. etc etc')
     if (!args[0]) return message.reply('Who?', { allowedMentions: { repliedUser: false } });
     const member = message.mentions.members.first() || await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]).catch(e => {
      check = true;
      return message.reply('Can\'t find specefied member! Provide a valid ID, or mention ig lol.', { allowedMentions: { repliedUser: false } });
    });
    message.channel.send(embed).catch(err)
    message.channel.send(`${member}`)
    }
```

Error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\stupk\Desktop\Holo\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\stupk\Desktop\Holo\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/843567563648139317/messages',
  code: 50006,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the value of `ws` when you try to send it? Can you try console logging it?

Comment: Its the embed, I renamed it to ws - but its back. and the error is in my edited question

Comment: Try doing `new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle('title').setDescription('description')`

Comment: Still same error.. Ima edit the question with my current code

Comment: Alright, I edited the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From discord.js v13 onwards, the API supports up to **10** embeds per message.

So, instead of:

```js
message.channel.send({ embed: embed })
```

Pass in an array of embeds instead:

```js
message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed1, embed2, embed3... embed10] })
```

You can, of course, just insert a single embed as well:

```js
message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
```

**Changelog:** https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#sending-messages-embeds-files-etc

You might find some extra stuff in there as well.

Comment: I'm using Discord.js v12.5.3 for a bot and I'm still having the same issue. Oddly enough, I get this error on one bot but not three others. All versions of Discord.js are the same, and the sending mechanisms are the same as well, the only thing that is different is the content of the embed. There is no async/await so I'm not sure what happened.

Comment: Actually never mind, I spelled the name of the embed wrong :P

Answer (score 0):

let me try to help! Lots of users recently encountered the same error!

Instead of:

```
message.channel.send(embed)
```

do:

```
message.channel.send({ embed: embed });
```