# discord bot embed code DiscordAPIError problem

Tags: discord, discord.js

im nemson

i have a problem with my embed code
this is the code i have for the embed

```
  if (message.content === prefix + "help") {
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Commandes")
      .setColor("#0099ff")
      .setDescription(
        "**-help** : Affiche les commandes du bot\n" +
        "**-ping** : Affiche le ping du bot\n" +
        "**-cat** : Affiche une image de chat\n" +
        "**-dog** : Affiche une image de chien\n" +
        "**-gif** : Affiche un gif random\n" +
        "**-anime** : Affiche un gif d'anime\n" 
      )
      .setFooter("Bot de test")
      .setTimestamp();
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }
});
```

but the problem is that wen i run the comand i get this error ant i dont know how to solv it
Uncaught DiscordAPIError DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
at DiscordAPIError (c:\Users\user\Documents\receptionist\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\DiscordAPIError.js:9:5)
at execute (c:\Users\user\Documents\receptionist\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

thx for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68239927/embed-discordapierror-cannot-send-an-empty-message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `message.channel.send(embed)`, discord.js thinks that the embed variable is a string and when it finds out that it isn't, it raises an error. To fix it, all you have to do is change it to:
`message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]})`