# DiscordAPIError[50006]: Cannot send an empty message

Tags: discord, discord.js

I don't know why, when someone joins my Discord, the error

"*DiscordAPIError[50006]: Cannot send an empty message"*

appears.

The code that I use:

```js
Client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${Client.user.tag}!`);
  });
  
  Client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    // This event is triggered when a new member joins the server
    const welcomeChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'général'); // Change 'général' to the name of your welcome channel
  
    if (welcomeChannel) {
      const avatar = member.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png', dynamic: true, size: 128 });
      const welcomeEmbed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor('#00ff00')
        .setTitle(`Welcome to the server, ${member.user.tag}!`)
        .setDescription('We are glad to have you here.')
        .setImage(avatar);
  
      welcomeChannel.send(welcomeEmbed)
    }
  });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68239927/embed-discordapierror-cannot-send-an-empty-message)

Answer (score 0):

To send an embed in Discord.js v14:

```js
import { EmbedBuilder } from "@discordjs/builders";

const embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
  .setDescription("Hello");

channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
```